# How can I capture a long press on a Menu Item?

Tags: java, android, menuitem, onlongclicklistener

I have a typical menu and I'm wanting to set a `onLongClickListener` for one of the items. In other words, I want this item to perform it's normal `onOptionsItemSelected` function, as well as, a long press function.

```
    MenuItem item;
    item = menu.findItem(android.R.id.home);

item.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Long Press";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by simply using setActionView on menuItem. You can follow this procedure if it helps.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        View v = new View(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //Your longclick listener callback logic goes here
                return false;
            }

        });
        menu.getItem(i).setActionView(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `findItem` method on `Menu` to get your views, and set your long click listener on each view.

Comment: no, there is a method on the Menu object called findItem. Use that to get a View, and set the long click listener on the View.

Comment: I get the same error. That OnLongClickListener is undefined in MenuItem. Can you offer anymore help?

Comment: Sorry, you need a handle to the View. Try getActionView() on the menu item.

Comment: I still haven't quite got the hang of it, but thanks for helping me.

Comment: I kept getting the same undefined error. I understand what to do, but I need to find where I'm messing things up. I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: And getActionView() returns null of course because my menu item doesn't HAVE an action view.. OP's question is how to capture a longpress on an MenuItem, not on an actionview of a menu item.

Comment: In Android you attach click listeners to Views. There is no other clickable elements, you can't click or long press etc on anything but some kind of View.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not right, it disturbs entire flow, but here you go:

```
    private interface OnMenuItemLongClickListener{
        boolean onMenuItemLongClik(MenuItem m);
    }
    private void getMenuItemsView(Activity a, final Menu m, final OnMenuItemLongClickListener listener) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        View homeButton = a.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        ViewParent parentOfHome = homeButton.getParent().getParent(); //ActionBarView is parent of home ImageView, see layout file in sources

        if (!parentOfHome.getClass().getName().contains("ActionBarView")) {
            parentOfHome = parentOfHome.getParent(); 
            Class absAbv = parentOfHome.getClass().getSuperclass(); //ActionBarView -> AbsActionBarView class
            Field actionMenuPresenterField = absAbv.getDeclaredField("mActionMenuPresenter");
            actionMenuPresenterField.setAccessible(true);
            Object actionMenuPresenter = actionMenuPresenterField.get(parentOfHome);
            Field actionMenuViewField = actionMenuPresenter.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
            actionMenuViewField.setAccessible(true);
            Object actionMenuView = actionMenuViewField.get(actionMenuPresenter);
            Field childrenField= actionMenuView.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mChildren");
            childrenField.setAccessible(true);
            Field menuField =actionMenuPresenter.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMenu");
            menuField.setAccessible(true);
            Object menu = menuField.get(actionMenuPresenter);
            Object[] menuItemsAsViews = (Object[])childrenField.get(actionMenuView);
            View.OnLongClickListener longListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    return listener.onMenuItemLongClik(m.findItem(v.getId()));
                }
            };
            for(Object menuView:menuItemsAsViews ){
                View v = (View)menuView;
                v.setOnLongClickListener(longListener);
            }


    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
            getMenuItemsViews(MainActivity.this, menu);
            }}, 100); //must be called after the menu views are generated, otherwise NPE.
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

MenuItem's in the overflow `WILL NOT` be considered.