# Toast on menu longpress is displayed at wrong position - android

Tags: android, split, optionmenu, contextual-action-bar

I have context menu - ICS 4.0.4 displaying menu options in the bottom.
Toast is displayed on its long press with text set as title to the menu.
Problem is, toast displayed is shown on top whereas it should be displayed just above the menu option.

Below is the code:

In Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SampleMenuActivityActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In Menu file:

```
<item android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:title="Title!"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

In Activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trial_option, menu);
    return true;
}
```

M I missing somthing?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't see the code you are using to show the Toast.

Comment: We do not need to write code in oder to display toast. It displays the the toast directly.

Answer (score 0):

On long press on actionBar item you always get a "toast" just above the item if title of item isn't visible and you can't modify or change this toast. But there is one alternative solution if you want to change postion of the toast:

-First you need to hide top toast. Instead of `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` use `android:showAsAction="withText"` but the title of the item will be shown.

-Now you need to handle long press on the item. I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18454874/3552945).