# Hold click menu item different than click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I currently have a menu that I load into my Toolbar which looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        android:title="Search"/>



    <item android:id="@+id/action_barcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/bar"
        android:title="barcode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="scanBarcode"/>



</menu>
```

When you click the barcode icon, it loads my barcode scanning fragment. I want to clean up my toolBar and not have multiple icons up there. Essentially I want my search icon, that opens up when clicked to have two functions.

1. When clicked open the search bar.
2. When long pressed, open my barcode scan fragment.

Currently Number one works, looking at how to employ number 2.

This is what my code looks liek for launching the barcode scan fragment and search.

```
import android.IntentIntegrator;
import android.IntentResult;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * Created by Mike and Simon on 2/22/14.
 */
public class MainDrawer2 extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);



        //Crashlytics.start(this);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_menu_white, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        //getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (mCurrentNavItem == null){


        }
        else{
            outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */



    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        //if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
        //  return;
        //}
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            //setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }

        //test to keep item not selected
        int toClear=mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

        if (toClear >= 0) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(toClear, false);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        //setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new Search();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

    public void scanBarcode(MenuItem item){

        //open scanner
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();



    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

            //todo: set scan content into setting, load new fragment which calls async task below. New
            //todo: fragment will have same ui as search. :-)
            Fragment Fragment_one;




            FragmentManager man= this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
            BarcodeFrag fragmentNew = new BarcodeFrag();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("scanContent", scanContent);
            fragmentNew.setArguments(bundle);


            tran.replace(R.id.main, fragmentNew);//tran.
            tran.addToBackStack(null);
            //tran.commit();
            tran.commitAllowingStateLoss();


        }

        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: I would suggest not using android:onClick.  Also, check to see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641573/how-can-i-capture-a-long-press-on-a-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

The action bar concept doesn't count on this requirement, so using built-in functionality you'll never be able to achieve what you need.
You can, however, introduce your own custom layout in stock action bar and do whatever you want there. See an example here:
http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android